# Mac Hebrew/English Uppercase

Tags: macos, mac, hebrew

On Windows, when I am typing in Hebrew, I can press Shift and a letter and get the English letter typed. This is very usefull as I don't have to change keyboard layouts all the time if I want to write mixed Hebrew/English texts.

On Mac, when I am using the Hebrew keyboard layout, pressing Shift and a letter does not do anything.

Is there any way to get Windows style functionality on the Mac?

I am using Mac OS X Leopard.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

7 years late but... I had the same problem and followed the thread here: https://discussions.apple.com/message/26461374 that helped me. Basically you go to System Preferences-> keyboard-> Input Sources and make sure that on the list of languages on the left you've got "Hebrew - PC" (rather then just "Hebrew"). I had "Hebrew", so I removed it with the minus button (bottom left) and then used the plus button (bottom left) the add the "Hebrew - PC" and that fixed it.

Comment: 7 years late and nobody gave the right solution until you did. This is indeed working.

Comment: also, in the standard Hebrew layout you can use CAPS-LOCK to temporarily switch to english (might need to leave CAPS pressed)

Comment: Thanks @waya! you saved me from going back and forth from English to Hebrew and back, cheers!

Comment: well, you are my prince

Comment: We are already in 2021 and your answer helped me a lot!! Thanks man

Comment: Thank you so much man! confirmed working on 2021 M1 Macbook, macOS Big Sur

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is already an existing keyboard layout for that, but you can use [**Ukelele**](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&item_id=ukelele&_sc=1) to create your own. It is not too difficult.
You can take the original Hebrew keyboard layout and extend it your way.

Comment: Thanks Felix. I can't seem to get this to work. Even if i just copy the original keyboard layout and edit a single key the new layout is not working (when I type using a custom layout, nothing is printed). I'll try some more when I have more time. good approach.